# How to show embedded google map in magento 2 in phtml file

Tags: magento2, phtml, google-map

I am trying to add google map in the frontend. I added embedded google map in phtml. here is my code

```
<?php
    $contacts_config = $this->getConfig('porto_settings/contacts');
    $_enable = $contacts_config['enable'];
    if($_enable){
        $_apikey = $contacts_config['api_key'];
        $_full_width = $contacts_config['full_width'];
        $_address = $contacts_config['address'];
        $_zoom = $contacts_config['zoom'];
        $_center_lat = $contacts_config['latitude'];
        $_center_lng = $contacts_config['longitude'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?<?php if($_apikey): ?>key=<?php echo $_apikey; ?><?php else: ?>v=3.17<?php endif; ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_center_lat; ?>, <?php echo $_center_lng; ?>);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: pos,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            zoom: <?php echo $_zoom; ?>
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("store_map"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            title: '<?php echo $_address; ?>'
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<?php if(!$_full_width): ?>
<div class="container">
<?php endif; ?>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php if(!$_full_width): ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I am getting a map but not for this location.

Comment: Try this way https://magehit.com/blog/static-block-how-to-embed-google-maps-into-the-magento-static-block/

Comment: yes. i did it and add it in phtml file but its not working

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: i am not getting any error. i am just getting simple world map

Comment: You mean location Popup not showing?

Comment: You want show marker on your dynamic location ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below link, it will solve your purpose.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

Comment: In the unlikely event that google move this page, this answer becomes useless. Try  not to answer with link only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this google map extension in magento 2 
Magento 2 Google Maps extension allows displaying the location of the store on Contact us Page, which makes the site look more informative and professional.

- Adding maps to contact page
- 4 maps types, 10 maps styles
- 2 choices of embedding Google maps
- Automatically get GPS coordinates
- Mobile responsive
- Compatible with Mageplaza Store Locator
- REST API, GraphQL is ready

Please follow this link to learn more about this implementation - https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-maps/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwmIuDBhDXARIsAFITC_7iOar0hLCg7w3tXnoZwwDWDGdPDcdOAEpo9G0UDyPYzRJl-kZVYbYaAosoEALw_wcB

Answer (score 0):

Apart from extension, you can also do so using page builder by inserting map API in the store backend and choosing which page to have the map shown. Step by step guide:
https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-add-google-map-on-a-magento-2-page.html